# Sending Strings to Microcontroller with iPhone over Bluetooth

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, bluetooth, microcontroller

I'm building an iPhone App which should control the color of a RGB LED which is connected to an "Microchip PIC" micro controller. The communication should happen via Bluetooth LE.

My first question: Is that possible? I really haven't found anything helpful on the internet yet.

And my second question is: Does anyone have a link to a working Sourcecode on github or something like that written in swift?

Comment: Have a look at some third-party BTLE modules - BlueGiga is one, but there are many others. These vendors supply source code samples and info on how to implement a system like this.

Comment: @Jon the problem is that BlueGiga only has samples written in objective c